# Nested foreach loop in R

Tags: r, parallel-foreach

I am reading [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/nested.pdf)

I have adapted the example in the above link to this:-

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cl = makeCluster(detectCores()-1)
registerDoParallel(cl)

bvec = c(2,4,6)
avec = c(1,2,3)

x <- foreach(b = bvec , .combine = 'cbind') %:%
    foreach(a = avec, .combine ='+') %dopar% {
    a+b
}
x
```

My query is that is the following allowed  :-

```
x <- foreach(b = bvec , .combine = 'cbind') %:%
c = b/2     #Is this allowed?
foreach(a = avec, .combine ='+') %dopar% {
a+b+c
}
x

stopCluster(cl)
```

In other words, is code in between the 2 loops legitimate ?

Comment: No, that's not possible. But why don't you test your code yourself?

Comment: Hi there, I wanted to be sure that there is no way of doing this. May I ask, did you read this somewhere ?

Comment: Read what somewhere? It's rare that people write down everything you can't do, they tend to focus on what you can do. In general, nesting of parallelized loops is rarely sensible, usually you get better performance by only parallelizing the outer loop. Parallelization means that tasks need to be send to the workers. In your first example, that's the `a + b` task. I don't even see a good conceptual way how your second example could work, so I'm pretty sure it's not possible with `doParallel`.

Comment: You can manually configure two levels of parallelization (see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50709474/5793905)), but you'd probably need a very specific use case to figure out if it's actually worth it.